# How to iterate selector over puppeter

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Dear everybody I have a problem with selector in puppeter.

I have this code.

```
for(var k= 0 ; k<= 21 ; k++) {
  const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector(
      'div.ui-table__row:nth-child('+k+') > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)'
    ).textContent
  })
  console.log(text);            
}
```

The problem when I try to execute this snippet is that I don't have defined k but i think that is correct.

```
 Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: k is not defined
```

How I can solve this problem ?
Regards

Comment: use `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` needs to be explicitly passed/injected into `evaluate()`

```
const k = 'foo'
await page.evaluate(k => {...}, k)
```

Change to:

```
for(var k= 0 ; k<= 21 ; k++) {
  const text = await page.evaluate((nth) => {
    document.querySelector(
      'div.ui-table__row:nth-child('+nth+') > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)'
    ).textContent
  }, k)
  console.log(text);            
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to pass this argument , I try your solution before publish this.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [document](https://pptr.dev/#?show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args), You have to pass the variable as an argument to the `page.evaluate` like this:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate((x) => { // 1. Define "x" to get value in the step 2
  return Promise.resolve(8 * x); // 3. Return the result
}, 7); // 2. Pass 7 to "x"
console.log(result); // prints "56"
```

Your snippet will look like this:

```js
for(let k = 0; k <= 21; k++) {
  const text = await page.evaluate((nth) => {
    return document.querySelector(
      'div.ui-table__row:nth-child('+ nth +') > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)'
    ).textContent; // Return `textContent` to "out side"
  }, k)
  console.log(text);            
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70428974/how-to-iterate-selector-over-puppeter/70429037#answer-70429037). Please consider editing existing answers to improve them.